# python check value not in unicode list

Tags: python

I have a list and a value and want to check if the value is not in the list.

```
list = [u'first record', u'second record']
value = 'first record'

if value not in list:
    do something
```

however this is not working and I think it has something to do with the list values having a u at the start, how can I fix this?  And before someone suggests the list is returned from Django queryset so I can't just take the u out of the code :)

Thanks

Comment: Do not name your lists `list` as this shadows the list class/type.

Comment: yeah good point. In my actual code I haven't done this but its always worth remembering

Comment: "this is not working" -- so what does it do?? You have not yet found out what the problem is/was. You have done `unicode(arg)` instead of `arg`. That's like saying "We waved a dead chicken at the volcano and it stopped erupting". If you gave us a meaningful example and stated what "not working" means, you could get some meaningful help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unicode(value)` transforms your `'first record'` into `u'first record'`. That might fix your issues. However, depending on the contents this might fail and you'll have to use the `.encode('charset')` function strings have.

PS: Your example is bad as those strings are equal in unicode and non-unicode and thus your example works fine.

Comment: yeah I agree.  The code I am using is being returned from Django models but I didn't want to include all this extra stuff so tried to shorten to just python code it but like you say in my example it would work.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see why it would not work:

```
s1 = 'hello'
s2 = u'hello'
s1 == s2 # True
```

Comment: yeah you are right.  I think it must be something to do with the way django is returning the objects rather than the python logic